# sql query difficulty with multiple left joins

Tags: sql, database

I am havin a query as

```
SELECT * FROM Issue I, Condition C, Result R, Status S      
            LEFT JOIN Issue as i1 ON C.ID = i1.ConditionID
            LEFT JOIN Issue as i2 ON R.ID = i2.ResultID
            LEFT JOIN Issue as i3 ON S.ID = i3.StatusID 
            WHERE I.ID = 452
```

which is giving me the error message:

> The multi-part identifier "C.ID" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "R.ID" could not be bound.

I want to have a result as follows:

> ID| IssueName| ConditionID| ResultID| StatusID| ID| ConditionName| ID|  ResultName| ID| StatusName

Comment: A comma is missing between Result R and Status S

Comment: Aside from the missing commas, I think your query is structured incorrectly anyway - do you really want to cross-join every row in Issue with every row in Condition, Result and Status, and then join to Issue 3 more times?

Comment: No I want to have them at one one time, IssueID| IssueName| ConditionID| ResultID| StatusID are from Issue,  ID| ConditionName frm Condition, ID| ResultName from Result,  ID| StatusName from Statu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's no JOIN between relation `I' and any other in your posted query, so you'll end up with a cartesian join here.

Using the old-fashioned joining the query might look like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Issue I, Condition C, Result R, Status S
 WHERE I.ConditionID = C.ID
   AND I.ResultID = R.ID
   AND I.StatusID = S.ID
   -- the filter comes here
  AND I.ID = 42;
```

Using ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Issue I
    LEFT JOIN Condition C ON C.ID = I.ConditionID
    LEFT JOIN Result R ON R.ID = I.ResultID
    LEFT JOIN Status S ON S.ID = I.StatusID
 -- the filter comes here
 WHERE I.ID = 42;
```

Comment: Of course, the "old-fashioned" one you show forces inner joins rather than left joins. To get left joins, you'd need to use dialect specific equality tests in the `WHERE` clause (e.g. SQL Server's `*=`, or Oracles `(+)` (I think, or was it `(*)`?)

Comment: There's a difference between LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: No, there isn't. `OUTER` is an optional keyword, and there is no other form of `LEFT` join than an `OUTER` one.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Then my 2 queries will yield different results. Still, given Issue table in subject contains FKs to the other columns, I doubt there will be a situation when FK will be referencing a non-existing PK entry. But this is for this particular case only.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try

```
SELECT *
FROM Issue I
LEFT JOIN Condition C ON C.ID = I.ConditionID
LEFT JOIN Result    R ON R.ID = I.ResultID
LEFT JOIN Status    S ON S.ID = I.StatusID
WHERE I.ID = 452
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is what they're actually aiming for.

Comment: If there are really spaces in your column names you have to mask them according to your DBMS - e.g. mysql likes ´column name´ (replace ´ with back-ticks) and mssql does [column name] I think...

Comment: how can i write a literal back-tick in a comment? like "´" but the other way around...?

Comment: I`ve corrected the spaces in the column names and they are as above, but still having the same error message

Comment: stupid question: your result-colum does have an ID-column...?

Comment: so you have Issue(ID,ResultID,ConditionID,StatusID,Value,s), Condition(ID,Value,s), Result(ID,Value,s), Status(ID,Value,s) ? than this query should work in quite any DBMS...

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that you are not using `MySQL Server`. try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Issue I, Condition C, Result R, Status S      
     LEFT JOIN Issue as i1 ON C.ID = i1.[Condition ID]
     LEFT JOIN Issue as i2 ON R.ID = i2.[Result ID]
     LEFT JOIN Issue as i3 ON S.ID = i3.StatusID 
WHERE I.ID = 452
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM Issue I LEFT JOIN Condition C ON C.ID = I.ConditionID
     LEFT JOIN Result    R ON R.ID = I.ResultID
     LEFT JOIN Status    S ON S.ID = I.StatusID
WHERE I.ID = 452
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Issue I, Condition C, Result R , Status S      
                                             ^---- You missing this
            LEFT JOIN Issue as i1 ON C.ID = i1.Condition ID
            LEFT JOIN Issue as i2 ON R.ID = i2.Result ID
            LEFT JOIN Issue as i3 ON S.ID = i3.StatusID 
            WHERE I.ID = 452
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your query:

```
Result R [comma is needed here] Status S
```